# Loading gif image in UIWebview - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

When Iam loading a gif image in    UIWebview in the iPhone 4.3 simulator it is getting an error like

```
ImageIO: <ERROR> _CGImagePluginInitGIFmalformed GIF frame#0 (640 x 960)
```

And the gif image is not showing. Can anyone help me...

Comment: use png instead of gif, I feel this issue only comes on simulator.

Comment: is it really a gif image?  can you open the gif using Safari on the iPhone?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes it is a gif image and I can open it using safari

Comment: you can make animation of multiple image in your imageView to show gif image functionality ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now in **iPhone**, Apple not supported `.gif` images.
You can use other type of images like png, jpg..

If you have a serie of images you want to animate you can easily do it with UIImageView:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];

self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3, nil];
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 7;
[self.imageView startAnimating];
```