# Animated GIF Image as a splash screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I have an animated GIF image and this has to be used as a Splash Screen. Could you please help me figure out how to develop an animated splash screen using the GIF?

Answer (score 8):

Use the builtin animation methods for UIImageView.  You'll need to create an NSArray of UIImages.  After that:

```
myImageView.animationImages = myArrayOfImages;
myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;   // forever
[myImageView startAnimating];
```

To do this with a GIF, you'd need to split the animated GIF into its individual images and then populate myArrayOfImages with one UIImage for each individual GIF image. UIImage supports PNG or JPEG representations.

[Edit] If you really must keep the animated GIF in tact, then create a UIWebView and load a URL to that GIF image.

Comment: Down-voting legitimate answers?  Hmmm.

Comment: That's a good way of using a gif image as a splash screen.Decomposing the .gif into a set of .png files and rendering those is workable; you would probably have to do a little bit of work to minimize what's loaded at first to get the animation to play which; of course; adds to the work of the launch. I prefer the progress bar based launch myself, though

Comment: It's not really a legitimate answer. He asked about the splash screen. Where do you expect this code to execute?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**

`GIF` image is not supported in `iOS`.

You can use multiple image with animation for this task after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Follow this for more [Loading gif image in UIWebview - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727281/loading-gif-image-in-uiwebview-iphone/14728666#14728666)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension: [UIImage+AnimatedGif](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif)

and do something like this:

```
+[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:(NSURL *)url]
```

and simply:

```
UIImage* mygif = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotating_earth_(large).gif"]];
```

Place this in applicationDidFinishLaunching of the App Delegate or the ViewDidLoad of your root view controller